# How do i stop the normal map from offsetting light?

Tags: normals

I'm making a project in a blender and the road has a normals map. However, when I add the normal map the light is offset. This is really annoying and it ruins the scene. I am using blender 2.8, but this also occurs in blender 2.79 for me. I have the image set as no color data, and I have inserted the normal map node. Hopefully, someone can help me. I'm probably missing something obvious but take a look at the pictures.

[!Photos!](https://photos.app.goo.gl/w9GkhUv5oB1sUZqa9)

[image: Without Normal]

[image: With Normal]

Comment: what do you mean with "offsetting light"? Please show some screenshots, or share your file with packed images: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I did. There is a hyperlink in the word "!Photos!" as it is blue. I'm using blender 2.8 so unless you have it there is no point in adding the file, but the picture shows you everything you need to know. I'll link it again. [https://Photos.google.com](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPEI26rjDJzPesYiR1wcD9YGGl-L7LAhjohJyJ7xTVaG0FwJkEnADX2FatgMxNWeQ?key=U19fdHVveHQ2NHg1ZVhpTFp6TVkwWloxMlZFQWxn)  @moonboots

Comment: I'm guessing this is a problem with a corrupt normal map. It would be interesting to see the normal map itself to be able to give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the normal map is doing but try turn the roughness down to see if it can combat whatever is happening. Also try applying a different normal map and see if it still offsets the light, and post pictures of the results.

Comment: I'v given up on this project an moved on. I think it was a bug, and I still encounter it today some times but I have to do some funky reloading maps one at a time to fix it. Its still happening in The beta 2.8 so i dont know if its an unfixed bug or something iv done.

Comment: Well its called beta for a reason :) Wait until blender 2.8 stable release and you should be good.